# What does $\sum$ mean without a starting index and limit?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I've seen this around, even on Wolfram|Alpha, and I don't know what it means.

Comment: General tip for interpreting mathematical notation: if information is omitted, it should be clear from the context.

Comment: Depends on the context. I see you tagged it as a "calculus" question and "algebra-calculus" question. In those areas, this sigma is probably being used as a sum. The fact that it lacks the startking index and limit is just that those are being ommited - they can be deduced from the rest of the text, from previous equations and so on. It's just an abbreviation.

Comment: writing down the entire formula would be helpful for a correct interpretation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sign $\sum$ denotes an [indefinite summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum), that is $g(n) = \sum f(n)$ (summation over $n$ is implied), such that $g(n+1) - g(n) = f(n)$.

For example $\sum n = \frac{n^2 - n}{2}$, since $\frac{(n+1)^2 - n-1}{2} -\frac{n^2-n}{2} = n$.

Comment: Nice. This makes me think of $\sum n$ as if it were $\int n$ and infer its "${\rm d}n$" from context.

Comment: Sometimes $\sum$ may mean indefinite summation.  But the author should say so, if it does.  In "calculus" or "precalculus" (the labels in this question) it probably does not mean indefinite summation.